# python error codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, sparql

I am running sparql query to people's name  from dbpedia for a give movie
After getting data I am displaying name as well as putting into Mysql 
I am getting normal names but at one pointit threw an error

I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestSparql.py", line 172, in <module>
    print person_Name
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 16-21: character maps to <undefined>
```

could some one explain what this error means and why it might have come?

Comment: You might find this other thread helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695567/unicodeencodeerror-when-fetching-urls

Answer (score 0):

That error means that Python is not able to encode as unicode your strings. Further details at http://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeEncodeError

In order to help you, many details are missing:

- SPARQL Python implementation you are using to query DBpedia
- The printing code that produces such error
- Some environment details (you charset configuration and so on)